# Laravel Best way to programming an interface

Tags: php, laravel, interface, laravel-5.3

I need a suggestion on this method to programming an interface.

Scenario: 
I need to implements a dummy class `ImageUploader` then receive an interface on the constructor and save the image in my directory. This is for learning purpose so I need your suggestions if I'm doing it the right way:

Here's my implementation on Laravel 5.3 framework:

1: Dummy interface to implements so I can create different way to storage my images

```
//dummy interface

namespace App\Lib\ImageUploader\Drivers;

interface ImageInterface
{
   public function hello();
}
```

2: Here two drivers that implements my interface. Each one as own method `hello` (in real life for example each class may have own save method for any kind of driver)

```
// Avatar Driver Class

namespace App\Lib\ImageUploader\Drivers;

class AvatarImage implements ImageInterface
{
     public function hello()
     {
          return 'I am a AvatarImage';
     }
}
```

and another one class, for example `BackgroundImage` can save desktop and mobile version of user uploaded image:

```
// Background Driver Class


namespace App\Lib\ImageUploader\Drivers;

class BackgroundImage implements ImageInterface
{
   public function hello()
   {
     // this is a dummy method, in real life this class will save 2 images (desktop + mobile)
     return 'I am a BackgroundImage';
   }

}
```

This is my `ImageUploader` Class with "Programming to interface" strategy:

```
// ImageUploader.php
// this class will implement all methods that I need for manage saving operations

namespace App\Lib\ImageUploader;
use App\Lib\ImageUploader\Drivers\ImageInterface;


class ImageUploader
{

   protected $driver;

   public function __construct(ImageInterface $driver)
   {
      $this->driver = $driver;
   }

   public function save()
   {
      return  $this->driver->hello();
   }
}
```

Now I create my own Laravel framework service Provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Lib\ImageUploader\Drivers\AvatarImage;
use App\Lib\ImageUploader\Drivers\BackgroundImage;
use App\Lib\ImageUploader\ImageUploader;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ImageUploadServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
   {
     //
   }

    /**
    * Register the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */

    public function register()
    {
       $this->registerAvatar();
       $this->registerBackground();
    }

    protected function registerAvatar(){
       $this->app->bind('AvatarUploader', function () {
          return new ImageUploader(new AvatarImage());
       });
    }

    protected function registerBackground(){
       $this->app->bind('BackgroundUploader', function () {
         return new ImageUploader(new BackgroundImage());
       });
    }
}
```

and at the end, I tried to use my class in my controller for example when the user tried to upload your avatar image or a new background image:

```
// this will produce "I am a AvatarImage" in real life this line create thumbnail and will save my image in my local directory

public function store(Request $request){
    (App::make('AvatarUploader'))->save();   
}
```

Is there the better way to to that? Any suggestion on my implementation?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations and https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#contextual-binding.

So in your Service Provider logic, you can specify -

```
$this->app->when(AvatarController::class)
          ->needs(ImageInterface::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new AvatarUploader();
          });

$this->app->when(BackgroundController::class)
          ->needs(ImageInterface::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new BackgroundImage();
          });
```

Then in your controllers or other classes, just dependency inject the `ImageInterface` interface rather than the concrete classes.

```
class AvatarController extends Controller
{
    protected $imageInterface;
    public function __construct(ImageInterface $imageInterface)
    {
        $this->imageInterface = $imageInterface;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->imageInterface->hello(); // returns "I am an Avatar Image"
    }
}

class BackgroundController extends Controller
{
    protected $imageInterface;
    public function __construct(ImageInterface $imageInterface)
    {
        $this->imageInterface = $imageInterface;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->imageInterface->hello(); // returns "I am a Background Image"
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i don't understand different between my method in service provider and yours with when...needs...give.... i need to create two separate controller Avatar and Background controller?

Comment: With my version, you inject the contract rather than the concrete class. That way, you move the responsibility out of the controller as to which implementation the controller runs. Your implementation however is different, in that what you are essentially doing is creating an alias for `new ImageUploader(new AvatarImage())` and simply calling it `AvatarUploader`. You are creating a shortcut - rather than separating concerns. It looks to me like your version could be adding complexity with little benefit as you may as well just inject the concrete class without the service provider.

Comment: I understand ;) thx Gavy but now i must create 2 controllers Avatar and Background, isn't it?

Comment: Ok i have create my two controller, AvatarController and BackgroundController, but i need to use in my UsersController (the default laravel users controller) how to implement? I need to pass it with a method to UsersController?